# Finding duplicates and entries that are almost duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with several thousand text entries.
In this table there are some entries that are exact duplicates.
Then there are entries which are almost duplicates like this:

```
Text

Hi my name is John. I am 25 years old. How are you? 
Hi my name is John.
```

These almost duplicates are shorter variants of a longer text.

Now I want to write a `select` statement which selects everything in the table, except the exact duplicates. Additionally I want to select the longer version of the almost duplicates.

Is it possible to do this in one statement?

EDIT: I forgot to add that the data is in the same column and not in two different ones.

Comment: Do `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove exact duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should do exactly what you want:

```
select distinct t.text
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.text like concat(t.text, '_%')
                 );
```

This should work even when the longest value is duplicated.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8532f3189364910eaf62a5fc7f35689) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I forgot to add that the data is in the same column and not in two different ones.

Comment: Additonally I get this error message: ```Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 2 String or binary data would be truncated. ```

Comment: @gython . . . I think that would only occur if you were trying to insert this data into another table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - did you post this answer purely for the underscore optimisation (which I like) or is there a bug in mine?

Comment: @RyanSparks . . . I thought there was a bug in your when I wrote this.  I then tested the two and I was wrong about the bug.

Comment: Take care if there might be '%' or '_' characters in the [text] values. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=489278935834d5a452b929a426733721

Comment: @SteveKass - good point, I've adjusted my answer to account for this.